# Interracting with Remote Etcd API

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, etcd

I am currently writing a custom terraform provider for etcd and would like to interact with the ETcd API, but i am yet to see any endpoint(Base url or otherwise) to interact with.

Please can someone point me to a resource or direct me on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etcd is using RPC and you can use [official Go etcd client for v3](https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3) to interact with it.